# Haskell: How to generate all possible combinations of elements, each element from a list, with arbitrary number of lists

Tags: haskell, functional-programming, combinations

Having a list of `["P", "Q", "R" ...]` I want to generate all possible list of `[(String, Bool)]` where on the left is a letter from the first array, and on the right is `True` or `False`. For example having `["P", "Q"]` I want to obtain 
: `[[("P",True),("Q",True)],[("P",True),("Q",False)],[("P",False),("Q",True)],[("P",False),("Q",False)]]`

I made it for the case where I only have `["P", "Q"]` but I need to suport arbitrary number of letters. I tought I can generate for every letter L two pairs in an array like `[(L,True),(L,False)]` and do that for every letter and make all possible combinations of those arrays with one element from each array, but I don't know how to do it properly.

That's what I did for the list of length 2 of letters

```
envs :: [String] -> [[(String, Bool)]]
envs predicate = let 
  env = [(p,b) | p <- predicate, b <- [True, False]]
  ps = filter (\(pred,val) -> pred == "P") env 
  qs = filter (\(pred,val) -> pred == "Q") env 
  in [[a,b] | a <- ps, b <- qs]
```

Comment: If you had a list of results [[("P",False),("Q",True)],...] from a recursive call, what would you need to do to have a new list of result for a new variable "Q"? You need to double each existing list in the result list, once for R being false and one for R being True

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Introduce this function

```
cartProdn :: [a] -> Int -> [[a]]
cartProdn ls 2 = [[x, y] | x <- ls, y <- ls]
cartProdn ls n = [x : t | x <- ls, t <- cartProdn ls (n - 1)]
```

This gives all possible combinations of length `n` of a finite list (`n > 1`).

Then do

```
*Main> ls = ["P", "Q", "R"]
*Main> rs = [zip ls c | c <- cartProdn [True, False] (length ls)]
*Main> putStrLn $ unlines $ map show rs
[("P",True),("Q",True),("R",True)]
[("P",True),("Q",True),("R",False)]
[("P",True),("Q",False),("R",True)]
[("P",True),("Q",False),("R",False)]
[("P",False),("Q",True),("R",True)]
[("P",False),("Q",True),("R",False)]
[("P",False),("Q",False),("R",True)]
[("P",False),("Q",False),("R",False)]
```

*note*: you might want to write `ls = "PQR"`.

Comment: Worked like charm ! Thank you :)